# Creating a File of Random Size [1...500] KB

Tags: c, ubuntu

*Foreword: I have simplified the problem into its key functionalities, so if it sounds weird it is because this is a small aspect of the whole program.*

**Problem:**

I want to create something like 100 text files: I'll loop and use my loop counter to name the files.

Then, I want to populate each file with random strings. I use my String struck defined below for this. I want to fill the file up from [1KB up to 500KB].

```
struct String // And yes I am using my own String library.
{
   char *c;
   int length;
   int maxLength;
}
```

Lets assume I have the file opened (probably at the moment I create it, so it is empty). Now I would check something like this.

```
int range = Random.Range(0,500);
```

I would get a number that would predetermine the file size. So if `range == 100` then the file would be populated with 100KB of "data".

I would first have my string created.

```
// Maybe making this 100 chars would help?
String *s1 = makeString("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

How would I figure out how many times I have to write my String `s1` into the file to make it the size of `range`? Preferably before writing to the file, I wouldn't want to write first then check, then write again.

And How would I get a random integer value in C? I used to the Random.Range in C#.

Comment: You mean preferred-file-size divided by string-length: `range * 1000 / s1->length;`?

Comment: To simplify things, ensure your string has a size dividing 1024, which is the number of bytes in a kilobyte. You need to write the string `(range*1024)/s1->length` times to have the desired size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, it would best if you can make your string size the common denominator of 1KB (1024 bytes). So you don't have to take care fraction.
After that you can do as @naitoon mentioned above (range*1024)/s1->length. If each of the character of your string is 1 byte long.

As for random integer, you can call the standard library rand() which returns integer between 0 to RAND_MAX, which is at least 32767.

Also, in order to keep the random number with your range(0~500), you can do a modular of the return value.

```
    range = rand() % 500;
```